# ajax responseText always returns the page itself but not the requested page

Tags: ajax, responsetext

I'm trying a very simple test for Ajax - changing a title. 
But instead of changing the title with the desired text from DoSomthing.php file, the ajax modifying the title with all my main.php file content.

The main file is a php file, but for the testing, no php code is needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    function myFunction2()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;            
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","DoSomething.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>        
</head>
<body>
    <p id="Title">What do you say? :)</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">Try Ajax</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The new title is given by php file that exists in the same folder as the main php file.
Here is the DoSomthing.php file that is called by Ajax for modifying the title.

```
<?php
echo "Hellooo there!";
?>
```

btw, No errors are reported in the debug console.

So I don't understand what's going here, and didn't find any similar problem in the web.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming the `<p id="Title">...</p>`

Comment: what do you mean renaming it?

Comment: Rename P id="Title" to any other name and call it in document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; with changed name

Comment: Thanks. "Title" was ok, the problem was found to be the browser cache that hold old code and need to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it!

The problem was caused by the cache mechanism of the chrome browser.
While developing the code, the chrome kept some of the old code in the cache so when I tried the example given in this question, the overall results were based on new code with old code that was cached.

Pressing F5 for refreshing the page solve it all.